# C++ strtok: how to get and assign

Tags: c++

I use the following code and get the output below.

Original string is `-CCY 1.2624 Up 0.0006(0.05%) 01:37 [37]`

```
char* pch;

 pch = strtok (buffer," ");

  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");

  }
```

This is my output

```
CCY
1.2624
Up
0.0006(0.05%)
01:37
SGT
[37]
```

How do I get the *1.2624* and assign it to a cstr so i can use it later like `printf` or something when outside of the while loop?

Comment: what is `cstr`? a C string or a C++ `std::string`?

Comment: Do you know it will always be the second token?

Comment: You do know that `strtok` is made with sadness and despair and that you should avoid using it in modern C++ code, _right_?

Comment: "Q: How do I do X with strtok? A: You don't use strtok." — [R. Martinho Fernandes](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4655847#4655847)

Comment: `strtok` is a broken API. Use [`boost::algorithm::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id820181.html) instead of `strtok`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* pch;

 pch = strtok (buffer," "); // pch == "CCY"
 // again:
 pch = strtok (NULL, " "); // pch == "1.2624"
```

Provided that `buffer` can be splitted to two or more items

Answer (score 1):

Since strtok uses a static buffer you need to make a copy of the string you're interested in using your own buffer. Something like:

```
char* numbuffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(pch));

if (numbuffer != NULL) {
   strcpy(numbuffer, pch);
}
```

More examples: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/

The reason you do this is because any subsequent call to strtok will change the value of the buffer pointed to by pch

Comment: Bad answer, a good answer would say "don't use strtok" and show how to do it properly.

Comment: The question wasn't asked, "should I use strtok?". Keeping it in scope.

Comment: But in response to "strtok need some help thanks" it is helpful to advise against it. The question was (quite sensibly) "how do I do xyz?" not "how do I do xyz with strtok?"